# js поменять содержимое html при условии , что динамическое содержимое значение другого атрибута html = определенному значению

Tags: javascript, html

```
 async function text(){
    var x = document.querySelector("#h");
      var q = x.innerText
    var y = document.querySelector("body > header > div > div.text-center > div.reverse > div:nth-child(2) > p");
    var z = y.innerText;

               if(q==="4"){
                   z='xxx'

       }
       window.setTimeout("text()",10);
}
```

Есть значения таймера ,по умолчанию стоит часов ,когда 2,3,4 = часа 1 = час хочу сделать,в чем ошибка
вот html js таймера
timeend= new Date();

```
timeend= new Date(2020,2,9,00,00);

async function time() {
    today = new Date();
    today = Math.floor((timeend-today)/1);
    tmsec=today%1000; today=Math.floor(today/1000); if(tmsec<100)tmsec='0'+tmsec;
    tsec=today%60; today=Math.floor(today/60); if(tsec<10)tsec='0'+tsec;
    tmin=today%60; today=Math.floor(today/60); if(tmin<10)tmin='0'+tmin;
    thour=today%24; today=Math.floor(today/24);
    timetoday= today ;
    timehour= thour;
    timemin= tmin;
    timesec= tsec;
    timemsec= tmsec;
    document.getElementById('d').innerHTML=timetoday;
    document.getElementById('h').innerHTML=timehour;
    document.getElementById('m').innerHTML=timemin;
    document.getElementById('s').innerHTML=timesec;
    document.getElementById('ml').innerHTML=timemsec;
    window.setTimeout("time()",10);
}

<body onload="time()"  onload="text()">
<div class="reverse"> 
                    <div class="time-block"><span id="d" ></span><p class="time-text">дней</p></div> 
                    <div class="time-block"><span id="h" ></span><p class="time-text">часов</p></div> 
                    <div class="time-block"><span id="m" ></span><p class="time-text">минут</p></div> 
                    <div class="time-block"><span id="s" ></span><p class="time-text">секунд</p></div> 
                    <div class="time-block"><span id="ml" ></span><p class="time-text">мс</p></div> 
                </div>
```

Comment: Где вызывается функция `textO`?

Comment: `<body onload="time()"  onload="text()">` - ??

Comment: это моя опечатка,не работает все равно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От того, что Вы изменили значение переменной `z`, текст внутри DOM-элемента не поменяется:

```
if (q == "1" || q == "21") {
  y.innerText = "час";
} else if (q == "2" || q == "3" || q == "4" || q == "22" || q == "23") {
  y.innerText = "часа";
} else {
  y.innerText = "часов";
}
```